# iOS: Issue while uploading hosted content inside of in-app purchase (ITMS-4200)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, xcode7, application-loader

I'm having an issue while uploading new hosted content inside of an already existing in-app purchase for an iOS app. Some background:

1. I'm using the app *Application Loader*.
2. Current app version is 1.2.3. I have the 1.2.4 slot created for a new app update.
3. The app has 9 localization/languages. One of them, Chinese.

The error I'm getting is: **ERROR ITMS-4200: "Version '1.2.3', Locale 'zh-cn': Cannot add locale because the app version is not editable"**.

How can I solve this?

Image attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all occurrences of "zh-Hans" to "zh-cn" in the itmsp file. This solved the problem in my case.